# URL getting blocked at security level after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, https, operating-system, f5

We recently had a windows upgrade 10 to patch version 10.0.18362. Before this we were able to connect to any URLs.

Aftermath is now we are not able to connect to a website which is hosted after a security device (WAF - web application firewall). CI_session (cookie value is now in different format value like - session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%2)

Just wondering does an operating system changes the HTTPs request format after a client sends it to the server.

Will need help on this. Not sure how to put this up and look for answers.

Comment: Why is this PHP tagged? I do not see any code or configuration to say something about this.

Comment: @MarkusZeller , apologies I didn't know how this ci_session works here. so added the php tag. haven't worked with PHP. so wanted to understand. All the ci_session does have was the hexacode with % values.

Comment: The HTTP request consists of two ci_sessions and that is why it is getting blocked. not sure how to fix this at the security end.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two separate paths going on here:

- Windows 10 patches
- A WAF implemented on your web app (is it F5's ASM, Advanced WAF or NGINX WAF, F5 was tagged).

That version of Windows by itself doesn't have issues related to connecting to URLs. If you have a VPN in the mix, then that does pose some changes that could affect your browsing sessions (split-dns versus full tunnel and such).

If the WAF is our potential culprit (using F5 as example since it was tagged) and there are blocking events by default the WAF will give you a message stating it was blocked along with an error code.

When rolling out a WAF policy in front of an application, the standard process is to run in transparent mode while learning the application. The WAF then understands the default behavior of that application (if going beyond default attack signatures). If the application is changed, it's standard practice to rerun learning and update the WAF policy as needed (usually done during test/stg processes).

Regardless, the WAF would generate warning or blocking events and this would be visible in analytics, logging, and a blocking page would present itself to the user being blocked (unless disabled - bad experience though).

Moving beyond the WAF aspect of this, if the application is indeed behind a BIG-IP, there may be load balancing methods involved using cookie persistence for the session.  The F5 BIG-IP will use a cookie insert or rewrite which clients use until the cookie/session expires (expiration based on persistence within the BIG-IP - more on that here: [AskF5 K6917](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K6917?sr=15914950)).

Depending on what system is responsible for the session, you should A) not see two separate ci_sessions and B) the BIG-IP would be responsible for the session state to the back end node.

Your client COULD be connecting to two back end nodes and receiving two separate sessions independent of each other. If that's possibly the case, then investigating how the F5 BIG-IP is determining persistence is needed.

If another persistence method was used you'll need to find out and resolve with the BIG-IP admin/app owners.  Example of persistence methods on BIG-IP v15. Either way, you'll need to find out how the application is deployed behind BIG-IP and if that changed. If the answer cannot be found within F5's [DevCentral](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/questions) community  or at [AskF5](https://support.f5.com/csp/home), then a ticket should be created. Cookie persistence on BIG-IP isn't difficult to implement but it's all dependent on how the application behaves.

[image: F5 BIG-IP v15 persistence methods]

If not, gather some more details and I can update this answer. Hope this helped at least understand the WAF and BIG-IP LB methonds.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer. I am still new to this F5 asm WAF and LB concepts. So it is possible to support multiple ci_sessions under the f5 lb and WAF.

Comment: Technically you could yes. As long as the client is persisting to the same app "node" for the duration of the session as defined by your BIG-IP configuration then you're ok. The node would be able to set whatever session cookies it wants to.  Mind you it's all dependent on what your app needs.

Your app may not like it or the client may not like it. The danger of flexibility is it's flexible. Applications may not be so forgiving. Either way, the BIG-IP is tune-able to resolve whatever your running into.

Comment: I know this is different issue, but I haven't found someone who is expert in f5 and web application at the same time. So I have across a content-type - application/ld+json where some context body as many '@id' value, where the f5 asm blocks it. The strange thing is if in body @ or id is removed it works perfectly without any blocking. I am not able to see any alerts and violations even when there is support id with respect to the blocking. I have tried everything from my end but still no luck.

Comment: My suggestion then would be post this to F5's DevCentral community. They not only have BIG-IP experience but WAF too. https://devcentral.f5.com/s/questions

Their WAF products are ASM & Advanced WAF (ASM = Application Security Manager), and Advanced WAF is a beefier version of that if I remember correctly.

But I am not sure if your issue is the WAF or something in the load balancing profile. The DevCentral community will be able to help figure that out with enough info.

We'll just make sure to post the resolution back to this thread to close it out.